# error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

Tags: image, import, arguments, opencv, python

I have installed opencv on my windows machine using python 3.10 without any issues, using:

pip install opencv-python
but when I try to import cv2 I get the following error:
usage: [-h] -i IMAGE
: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

I tried to import cv2 but got error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import cv2
usage: [-h] -i IMAGE
: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image   ,  in visual studio code I get this error: usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -i IMAGE
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2